# Intersection of planes and calculating the equations

Tags: plane-geometry

Two planes:

4a - 6b + 8c = 3

-9a + 12b -3c = -10

What steps are there to calculate the equation of the line when the planes intersect?

Comment: set them equal.

Comment: What form of equation of a line do you want to end up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying the second equation by $4$ and adding to the first one  we get
$$x=1+\frac{13}{10}y$$
defining $$y=10t$$
we get $$x=1+13t$$ and plugging this in one of the equation above we get $$z=t$$ so our line is given by 
$$[x,y,z]=1,0,0]+t[13,10,1]$$ where $t$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple way it's the following.

Let $z=t$ and solve the following system:
$$2x-3y=2-4t,$$
$$-3x+4y=-3+t$$ and $$z=t.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $$(1+13t,10t,t).$$